# How to run python program on pycharm's Run tool windosw, instead of python console?

Tags: python, pycharm, console, output, display

I have PyCharm 2020.2 in my windows 10 computer.

Earlier, when I used to Run(https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-running-your-first-python-project.html#run) my python programs in PyCharm, its output used to be on its (default) Run tool window(https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-tool-window.html).

Now however, after clicking the 'Run File in Python Console' option, the output appears in the Python console(https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-consoles.html), whenever I Run the Python program.

I just want to get the Run tool window back (as default), for displaying the outputs.
Kindly Help.

Answer (score 1):

You can change how to run your code when clicking on 'Edit Configurations' in the top right ([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqLza.png)), then uncheck 'Run with Python Console' and click 'OK' or 'Apply'